# How can I make a fragment replace actionbar menu behavior?

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-menu, slidingmenu

Before I start, yes I have read countless related questions. I still can't seem to track down the issue.

I have a SherlockFragmentActivity:

```
package com.kicklighterdesignstudio.floridaday;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class FragmentActivity extends BaseActivity {

public static final String TAG = "FragmentActivity";

public static final int SCHEDULE_FRAGMENT = 0;
public static final int MAP_FRAGMENT = 1;
public static final int FOOD_FRAGMENT = 2;
public static final int TWITTER_FRAGMENT = 3;
public static final int HASHTAG_FRAGMENT = 4;

private Fragment mContent;

public FragmentActivity() {
    super(R.string.main_activity_title);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
    switchContent(SCHEDULE_FRAGMENT);
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);

}

public void switchContent(int id) {
    getFragment(id);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent)
            .commit();
    getSlidingMenu().showContent();
}

private void getFragment(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case 0:
        mContent = new ScheduleFragment();
        break;

    case 1:
        mContent = new FoodFragment();
        break;

    case 2:
        mContent = new MapFragment();
        break;

    case 3:
        mContent = new TwitterFragment();
        break;

    case 4:
        mContent = new HashtagFragment();
        break;
    }
}

}
```

It extends BaseActivity:

```
package com.kicklighterdesignstudio.floridaday;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;

import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu;
import com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity;

public class BaseActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

//  private int mTitleRes;
protected ListFragment mFrag;

public BaseActivity(int titleRes) {
//      mTitleRes = titleRes;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

//      setTitle(mTitleRes);
    setTitle("");

    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mFrag = new MenuFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
        t.commit();
    } else {
        mFrag = (ListFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.menu_frame);
    }

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
    sm.setBehindScrollScale(0.0f);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        toggle();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

}
```

Right now, I'm only concerned with ScheduleFragment:

```
package com.kicklighterdesignstudio.floridaday;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;

public class ScheduleFragment extends SherlockFragment implements OnItemClickListener {

public static final String TAG = "ScheduleFragment";

private ArrayList<ScheduleItem> schedule;
private FloridaDayApplication app;

public ScheduleFragment() {
//      setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    app = (FloridaDayApplication) activity.getApplication();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_fragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.schedule_fragment);

    schedule = app.getSchedule();

    ListView scheduleListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.schedule_list);
    ScheduleItemAdapter adapter = new ScheduleItemAdapter(getActivity(), schedule);
    scheduleListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    scheduleListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int id, long position) {

    Fragment newFragment = new ScheduleItemFragment(id);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

}

}
```

ScheduleFragment displays a list of schedule items. When clicked, a new fragment is displayed (ScheduleItemFragment) to show details of the item and a map to its location:

```
package com.kicklighterdesignstudio.floridaday;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class ScheduleItemFragment extends SherlockFragment {

public static final String TAG = "ScheduleItemFragment";

private int scheduleItemId;
private FloridaDayApplication app;
private ScheduleItem scheduleItem;
private MapView mapView;
private GoogleMap map;

public ScheduleItemFragment(int id) {
    scheduleItemId = id;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    app = (FloridaDayApplication) activity.getApplication();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_item_fragment, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    // Initialize MapView
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map_view);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    scheduleItem = app.getSchedule().get(scheduleItemId);
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setTitle(scheduleItem.getTitle());

    // Map Stuff
    map = mapView.getMap();
    if (map != null) {
        map.getUiSettings();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Add marker to the map
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions().position(scheduleItem.getLocation().getPosition()).title(
                scheduleItem.getLocation().getTitle());
        map.addMarker(options);

        // Adjust Camera Programmatically
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                scheduleItem.getLocation().getPosition(), 14);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Map is null");
    }

    // Other Views
    TextView title = (TextView) getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView time = (TextView) getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.time);
    TextView description = (TextView) getSherlockActivity().findViewById(R.id.description);

    title.setText(scheduleItem.getTitle());
    time.setText(scheduleItem.getDateTimeString());
    description.setText(scheduleItem.getDescription());

}

// TODO: Make this work
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mapView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    mapView.onLowMemory();
    super.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mapView.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mapView.onResume();
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

}
```

Thanks to BaseActivity, the icon in my ActionBar is clickable. It toggles the Sliding Menu. When viewing a ScheduleItemFragment, I would like the icon to return to the previous item in the backstack (which you can see I'm trying to do.) No matter what I try, the icon always toggles the Sliding Menu. Any thoughts on how to guarantee my Fragment gains control of the ActionBar menu clicks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onCreate`, not `onCreateView`

also I'm interested what happens when you debug, does onOptionsItemSelected still get called?

edit: add the following to your fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

edit1:
there may be a better way to do this but I'm not exactly sure how your fragments are setup out, create a public field in baseActivity `public bool isItemFragmentOnTop`
now `onOptionsItemSelected` in the case of the home button getting press do this

```
if (isItemFragmentOnTop){
   getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
   isItemFragmentOnTop = false;
} else {
   toggle();
}
return true;
```

then in your fragment you can call `((BaseActivity)getActivity).isItemFragmentOnTop = true;` to make the home button pop the back stack, you would want to do this when you display your fragment onItemClick in your list view.

Comment: I call `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in ScheduleItemFragment's `onCreateView` method. What `onCreate` are you referring to? Also, are you asking if the Fragment's `onOptionsItemSelected` gets called?

Comment: you need to override OnCreate in your Fragment and call it from there, I'll update with an example, and yes that's what I was asking

Comment: Oh, I was unaware I needed to override onCreate... I tried that though and it still didn't work. Added a Log to the Fragment's onOptionsItemSelected and it never gets called.

Comment: then I suspect that your parent activity is catching the event before it gets down to the fragment, see in the baseActivity you're catching the home event and returning true, which means you handled the event and it doesn't need to be passed further down the line, you need to figure out in your activity if you need to pop the backstack or not.

Comment: I'd also recommend you take a look at this guide on debugging, http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html using log sucks to debug with.

Comment: Also, my Fragment's onCreateOptionsMenu is never called. So you're suggesting I listen for the icon click where I'm already listening (BaseActivity) and from there decide if I should pop the backstack or toggle the sliding menu? How would I be able to determine what Fragment is loaded when the user clicks the home icon?

Comment: Yeah, I know how to use Eclipse's debugger. I just prefer a simple log message when I just want to know if I method was called.

Comment: I edited my answer with a simple way to manually make a check for the fragment.

Comment: That's a more elegant way than I was thinking. Althought I'd rather have the fragment be able to take control of the options menu, this will at least cause the appearance of everything working as I'd like them to. Thanks!

Comment: no problem as usual there are so many ways of solving this I figured I'm just post the most straight forward and let you take it from there.